# How can I ask jenkins to execute one job before another job?

Tags: jenkins

I will create many jobs everyday, each of them depends on one job called **baseline**. Sometimes I may forget to execute the baseline job manually. 
I want to know If the baseline job can be executed automatically before the target job is executed.

What I want is : I only need to one click my target job, then the target job will not start until the baseline job was scheduled and **finished**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the thing you need is "Build another project" in "post build actions".

Comment: It seems the  "Build another project"  be will execute after my target job.

Comment: Ah, so then you need to block the downstream job? Something like http://i.stack.imgur.com/5soP0.png ?